# Can't exclude some strings

Tags: python

```
ASCII_LOWERCASE='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ASCII_UPPERCASE='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ASCII_ALL=ASCII_LOWERCASE+ASCII_UPPERCASE

def is_alpha(x):     
    for ch in x:        
        if ch not in ASCII_ALL:
            return False
    return True
```

This was my original code and it is still not returning `False` in cases like `""`. When the real `isalpha()` returns `False` in the case of `''` or `""`. How to exclude all these cases?

Comment: I don't understand, is the empty string your only problem?

Comment: Have you tried `len(x)<=0` or `x==""`?

Comment: how bout `return x and True`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That is equivalent to doing `return x`. You probably mean `return bool(True and x)`.

Comment: naw I changed it it should return true or false now

Comment: Btw. `''` is the *exact same* string as `""`. Also you don’t need to define `ASCII_LOWERCASE` etc., you can take them from the [`string` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Comment: How's this different from your previous question [is_alpha coding that works like isalpha() in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763469/is-alpha-coding-that-works-like-isalpha-in-python)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty strings will not trigger any code in the for loop, since `for ch in ''` is essentially a no-op here (there's nothing to iterate), so your `is_alpha` returns `True` for empty strings. You should add something like

```
if not x:
    return False
```

to the beginning of your function.

(As a side note, your `break` statement is unnecessary since `return False` will exit the function.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your input. I didn't know of any such thing as no-op. My textbook even doesn't talk about no-op. So, finally the codes are working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Your loop

```
for ch in x:
```

Will *never run* if `len(x) == 0`, you go straight to

```
return True
```

Also, if you

```
import string
```

You can use `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase`.